# Replacing a layer of an existing model in tf keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I load a pretrained model. However, I want to add Spectral Normalization to this model.

I can do it in this way if the model is fully sequential:

```
import tensorflow as tf

base_model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(input_shape=(720, 1280, 3), weights=None, include_top=False)

# Add spectral normalization
base_model_new = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
for layer in base_model.layers:
    if isinstance(layer, tf.keras.layers.Conv2D):
        spec_norm_layer = SpectralNormalization(layer)
        base_model_new.add(spec_norm_layer)
    else:
        base_model_new.add(layer)

input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(720, 1280, 3), name='image')
x = base_model_new(input)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[input], outputs=x, name='test')
```

However, this method does not work when for example using a ResNet where there are Add or Concatenate layers which expect a list of inputs. How to solve this for ResNets?